# Problem with connectorConfig in direct link for MULTIPLE field

Tags: looker-studio

When transferring connector config via a direct link, it does not work for MULTIPLE field. I tried different options:

- `https://datastudio.google.com/u/0/datasources/create?connectorId=...&connectorConfig={"project_id":"[11]"}&reportTemplateId=...`
- `{"project_id":"11"}`
- `{"project_id":["11"]}`
- `{"project_id":"[\"11\"]"}`

```
function getConfig(request) {
  var cc = DataStudioApp.createCommunityConnector();
  var config = cc.getConfig();

  var option1 = config.newOptionBuilder()
  .setLabel("11")
  .setValue("11");

  var info1 = config.newSelectMultiple()
      .setId('project_id')
      .setName('Name project')
      .addOption(option1)
      .setAllowOverride(true);

  config.setDateRangeRequired(true);

  return config.build();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: 10-17-2019

Turns out this was a bug! Thanks for bringing up the issue. It should be resolved now. The correct format is an array of strings (the second 3rd bullet point above).